# passing function to a class using @property.setter decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, python-3.5

I am making a class that  i want to declare a variable which hold a function in it and i want to call them after i do some processing on some information.but i don't know how to use property decorator in this situation.
i already have this code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.callback = None
    def run():
        #do something here...
        result = self.callback(result)
        print(result)

def func1(result):
    result = result ** 2
    return result

def func2(result):
    result = result ** 4
    return result


class1 = MyClass()
class1.callback = func1
class1.run()
class1.callback = func2
class1.run()
```

my question is how i can use `@property` and `@property.setter` and `@property.getter` decorator for self.callback in this code?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use properties at all? What's the *problem* with the code you have now?

Comment: thats because i want to learn how to work with property decorator.why it is not good practice to use @property here?

Comment: Because you don't need one. There's no point obscuring access to the attribute unless you have validation rules or some other actual *reason* to do it. And if you just want to learn, why didn't you read a tutorial rather than asking this question?

Comment: oh i see,i read the docs and some tutorials but i seem to misunderstand it.thanks for help

Comment: Then a better question would show a [mcve] of what you tried and an explanation of the problem with it. This isn't a tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I based on this code don't see a need for `properties` but here it is anyway.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__callback = None

    @property
    def cb(self):
        return self.__callback

    @cb.setter
    def cb(self, new_cb):
        self.__callback = new_cb
```